# "Pardonnez mon français" in an e-mail

Tags: correspondance

I'm writing a French e-mail to an administrative worker at my university. Is there a way how to nicely excuse my French (in the literal meaning, not the idiomatic one)?

I thought of something like this, but I'm not sure if it's a good way:

> Chère Mme X,
>   (Pardonnez mon français.) Je suis un thésard en co-tutelle ....
>   ...
>   ...

However, I'm not sure if it serves any good. Is it good to excuse to French people if your French is far from perfect? Is there a polite and non-intrusive way how to do so?

Comment: "Thésard" is too familiar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Veuillez excuser mon français” sounds better, because you have a good excuse. And it's not standard but I think in this case the brackets are good style too.

Answer (score 1):

Saying «*Pardonnez mon français*» is not very positive here. If I read this, I feel you are not confident, so I don't know if I can trust you.
I think you may introduce yourself, saying that you made an effort writting in french and hope to be well understood.
I think it would be a more positive way to say it, and would show your motivation.

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

```
Chère Madame X, 

Je vous prie tout d'abord d'excuser mon français approximatif. 
Je suis doctorant en co-tutelle...
```

With a capital M and "doctorant" instead of "thésard".

I don't know what you mean by "co-tutelle", but if it means that you have two (or more) "directeurs de recherche", you could make a longer sentence to make it understandable.

Comment: She certainly knows what "co-tutelle" is :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Il n'est pas interdit de contourner les formules officielles et de personnaliser légèrement votre mél :

> Madame<sup>*1*</sup>,
>
> ... motif de votre courriel,
>
> ... éventuellement les éléments récents de votre C.V.
>
> Comme vous pouvez vous en rendre compte (ou Comme vous le voyez) mon français n'est pas complètement maîtrisé, mais ... (et vous donnez des  arguments qui vous engagent à progresser<sup>*2*</sup>).
>
> ... suite ...

---

<sup>*1* - Dans un courriel administratif on n'est pas obligé de nommer la personne, surtout si on ne l'a jamais rencontrée ; ici tout dépend des usages et de votre proximité avec votre correspondante.

*2* - De cette façon, vous admettez la gène que la lecture de votre lettre  peut occasionner, vous faites acte d'humilité et de respect en assurant que vous ferez tout pour que cela disparaisse au cours de l'année à venir.</sup>

Comment: If you consider that your French is not perfect, then I think you should avoid such a complicated sentence which will clearly appear copied/pasted from elsewhere. I find the proposals of @StéphaneGimenez more natural, and also shorter, which is good because your lack of proficiency is probably not the main topic of your mail (and you need to get to the point).

Comment: @Eusebius En effet, et j'ai d'ailleurs 'plussoyé' la réponse de Stéphane, mais la formule proposée peut différencier la candidature, et convenir à un candidat qui recherche aussi la maîtrise du français, qui peut déjà lire le français soutenu (fait une version) et qui s'exerce au thème pour préparer ses oraux.

Answer (score 0):

If he knows you're not fluent, you don't need to write it.